# C: Trying To Dynamically Allocate Space For Struct, Populate w/Data, and Assign Pointer to Struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

I need to take information from a text file in the given format:

last name, first name

street address

city, state

zip code

---

last name, first name

street address

city, state

zip code

etc...

I'm assuming that I don't know the number of entries, so obviously I will have to dynamically allocate space. I also need to use an array of pointers to point to each struct. At the moment, I'm only concerned about using malloc to allocate the space, assign values to the struct, assign the ptr to the struct, and then to output the given information. I will use IO redirection to take the data from a txt file (which I know how to do).

The errors that I'm getting are on the printf() on the bottom (error: request for member ‘name’ in something not a structure or union), but I suspect I have more things wrong with my code

Appreciate the help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct addressBook{

    char name [50];
    char streetAddress [50];
    char cityAndState [25];
    int zip;

};

int main(){

    int *ptr[50];

    int i, k;
    unsigned ptrCount = 0;

    for (i = 0; i != EOF; i++){

        struct addressBook *newAddress = malloc(sizeof(struct addressBook));

        gets(newAddress->name);
        gets(newAddress->streetAddress);
        gets(newAddress->cityAndState);
        scanf("%d", &newAddress->zip);

        for (k = 0; k < 50; k++){

            *ptr[k] = &newAddress;
            ptrCount++;

        }
    }

    putchar('\n');

    int z;
    for (z = 0; z < ptrCount; z++){

        printf("%s \n%s \n%s %d\n", *ptr[z].name, *ptr[z].streetAddress, *ptr[z].cityAndState, *ptr[z].zip);

    }
}
```

Comment: Compile with full warnings and fix them.

Answer (score 1):

Your ptr array is declared as an array of pointers-to-integers.  I think you meant to declare it as an array of addressBook pointers instead:

```
struct addressBook * ptr[50];
```

which you would then assign values to like this:

```
ptr[k] = newAddress;
```

and print like this:

```
printf("%s \n%s \n%s %d\n", ptr[z]->name, ptr[z]->streetAddress, ptr[z]->cityAndState, ptr[z]->zip);
```

It doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me to have a loop that assigns each newly allocated addressBook object to every one of the 50 pointers in the ptr array.  Perhaps instead of the

```
for (k = 0; k < 50; k++){
   *ptr[k] = &newAddress;
   ptrCount++;
}
```

loop section, you just want to do a simple:

```
ptr[ptrCount] = newAddress;
ptrCount++;
```

?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Working on it now.